# Function overloading in C shared libary (different return type, different amount of arguments)

Tags: c, operator-overloading, return-value

I have the job to create a shared library which should be useable as a replacement for several (older) versions of an other shared library.

Now the problem:

I have to combine:

Library a:

```
const char *mixer_ctl_get_enum_string(struct mixer_ctl *ctl, unsigned int enum_id);
const char *mixer_ctl_get_name(struct mixer_ctl *ctl);
```

Library b:

```
int mixer_ctl_get_enum_string(struct mixer_ctl *ctl, unsigned int enum_id, char *string, unsigned int size);
int mixer_ctl_get_name(struct mixer_ctl *ctl, char *name, unsigned int size);
```

I found out how to handle several amounts of input-params, but now they also have different return-types. I found examples for this in C++, but not for C.

How can I do this?

If C would work like Java, I would just implement both and everything is fine, but in C?

Thanks for your help & kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy or general solution.

In C++ you could package up functions into classes, and function names only have to be unique in the class.  C doesn't have this.

In C++, the return type and types of arguments count as part of a function name (so `void foo(int)` and `void foo(float)` are actually different functions and the compiler knows which one to call).  C doesn't have this.

In C there is a single, global namespace, and the types do *not* count as part of the function name.  As others have noted, the standard C function names are different for different return types: `sqrt()` returns `double` but `sqrtf()` returns `float`.

There are functions in C that can take a varying number of arguments; a classic example is `printf()`.  But these are tricky to write, and not a general solution to your problem.  In the case of `printf()` there is a "format string" argument, and the `printf()` function just has to trust that the format string correctly matches up with the arguments to `printf()`.  (Well, since `printf()` is common, some compilers actually check the format string against the arguments, but your library functions don't have this advantage!)

I've done a lot of work in C, and the single global namespace is one of the most annoying limitations of C.  Is there any chance that you can actually use C++ for this project?  If you use the basic features of C++, you can treat it as "C with classes" and just take advantage of namespaces and function overloading.

Otherwise I think your best bet is to use a refactor tool, or a really good search-and-replace feature in a text editor, to change the function names to be globally unique.  An obvious way to do this is to change every function to have the library name as a prefix:

```
const char *a_mixer_ctl_get_name(struct mixer_ctl *ctl);  // library a
int b_mixer_ctl_get_name(struct mixer_ctl *ctl, char *name, unsigned int size);  // library b
```

Then you would have to refactor or search-and-replace the programs using the old libraries, but since the libraries are mutually contradictory you should have an easy time getting things working again.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I noticed the printf-version with multiple arguments - I would use that style if there wheren't the problem with the different return type. I have to join 2 libraries written in C and I think I can use C & C++ for this (but I have absolute no knowledge of C++, I'm a beginner in C). If I would write the library in C - can the old programs also use it transparently? I have no chance to change the old programs using the libraries, because there are too many (unknown) users of it.

Comment: @MartinM. The interface your new library proivdes has to be the same as the old does to work transparently. C++ exports it's functions with different naming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and are therefore not "visible" to the applications unless you export them as "C" functions.

Comment: Hm okay, thank you very much. This means I have to find an other solution (there is no "magic, undefined, cast how you like" return type in C, isn't it? :)

Comment: @MartinM. Correct. The reason is, that the signature is not stored with the function name. In my answer I have made a proposal how to deal with your problem.

Comment: Also, there is one problem you cannot solve even with C++: if two libraries have functions with the same name, and the same types, but do something different.  If the libraries are big enough, this could actually happen.  The refactor approach solves this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function overloading in C.

Reason is that there is no name mangling in assembly generation. In C++ overloaded functions with different types will have different mangled names, in C -- not.

So common practice is to specify different name for function with different type, like

```
float sqrtf(float x);
double sqrt(double x);
long double sqrtl (long double x);
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

C does not provide function overloading facilities, neither does the shared library mechanism. The only way to differentiate the function calls will be to have different names.

To solve your problem of different interfaces (return types, parameters, ...), I'd suggest to build 3 shared libraries:

1. A shared library with combined functionality with a certain interface
2. A proxy shared library for application A, providing the interface expected, passing the calls to the combined library
3. A proxy shared library for application B, providing the interface expected, passing the calls to the combined library

Needless to say, that you sould change the application A & B somewhen over time to make direct use of the combined library.